# How to split the string in C#?

Tags: c#

Note:

```
string s="Error=0<BR>Message_Id=120830406<BR>"
```

What's the most elegant way to split a string in C#?

Comment: How do you want your results to be grouped?

Comment: As others have suggested, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx

Answer (score 10):

Use [String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

Supposing you want to split on the `<BR>` elements:

```
string[] lines = s.Split(new[] { "<BR>" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Note that this will *strip out* the `<BR>` elements themselves. If you want to include those, you can either use the [`Regex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx) class or write your own method to do it (most likely using [`string.Substring`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs.aspx)).

My advice in general is to be wary of using regular expressions, actually, as they can end up being rather incomprehensible. That said, here's how you might use them in this case:

```
string[] lines = Regex.Matches(s, ".*?<BR>")
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(m => m.Value)
    .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Slit string and here is the code:

```
string s = "Error=0<BR>Message_Id=120830406<BR>";
string[] stringSeparators = new string[] { "<BR>" };
string[] result = s.Split(stringSeparators, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Edit: Linq updated.
Good example:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf.aspx